# One Carrierwave Uploader shared between Two Models in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have one CarrierWave Uploader called **documents**.

Three Models:

1. University
   **has_many :documents**
2. WebinarContent
   **has_many :documents**
3. Document

   **belongs_to :university

   belongs_to :webinar_content**

I currently have ActiveAdmin setup:
**app/admin/document.rb**

```
belongs_to :university
```

That works well, however, when I try adding another belongs_to :webinar_content association, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find University with 'id'=
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your schema, its hard to tell. Though I suspect you want polymorphic associations.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations#polymorphic-associations

Basically you want your document to `belongs_to :documentable` having a `documentable_id` and a `documentable_type` on the `Document` model.

Then on your other models you wish to upload documents to you have `has_many :documents`

Comment: I had a feeling it was going to be polymorphic. What shall I place in the `document.rb` in the activeadmin?